# Encoding Error when Appending to CSV Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, csv, selenium, encoding, utf-8

So I am writing a web scraper in Selenium that appends to a CSV file in Python 3.6. This is the code I am using right now.

```
with open('webscraped.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow([str1, str2, str3])
```

My problem is when I scrape this site which is in Spanish, it appends characters into the CSV like Ã³n acadÃ©mica: Â·. This only happens when I set the mode to 'a' when opening the file which is append mode. When I switch to 'w' it works out fine for some reason and gets rid of the characters, but it overwrites the line it got from the webscraper and adds the new line. It ends up overwriting it because 'w' creates a new file or something like that from what I got from the description in the documentation. I looked on how to append in 'w' for CSV's but can't find any or it just says switch to 'a' and encode to 'utf-8-sig', but that doesn't work.

I want to append to the CSV each time the webscraper something which it does in the code, but I want to get rid of the encoding. If someone can point me in a direction about a library or something I am overlooking as I write to the CSV. The solutions I have seen are not for latin-1. Also I tried that too, but that doesn't work either. I thought of saving the results of the webscraper to a list or something and then write the results, but in case I want to use the scraper again, I want to just run the script and have it append lines to the same file. The script already has a way of finding duplicate lines.

So to sum things up, is there a way to append to a CSV and get rid of the encoding every time I extract something? Please let me know if I don't make sense, I am not clear or, I am getting something wrong conceptually about encoding.

Comment: I just tried your code with `str1="Manténgase sano y saludable"` and it works fine for me on 3.6.3?

Comment: I downgraded to Python 3.6.3 and ran my webscraper again, but I still get things like   'Excelente PronunciaciÃ³n'?

Comment: Can you updated the question with a sample script you try? I can try the same one here. Also delete the file and let it create a fresh one for your retest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your script is doing all (or most of) the encoding fine, but that the text is displayed badly by the tool you use to look at the output.
The source of the problem could be something else, but if you work on Windows and use a tool like Notepad to inspect the output, then it's quite probable that the following is happening.

For some (historical?) reason, the Windows ecosystem never got to like UTF-8, despite its popularity in the WWW.
Instead, native software tends to work with either 8-bit encodings like "Windows-1252" (derived from Latin-1), or UTF-16 (often called "Unicode").
One way to get such tools work with UTF-8 is to use a [byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which means that an invisible character is prepended to the text.
This character is encoded to bytes differently for all UTF-x encodings, so by inspecting the first couple of bytes, the reader software can tell what encoding is being used.

If the BOM is "missing" from a UTF-8 file (which is fine in theory, but not when working on Windows in practice), some tools will interpret the data by using an 8-bit encoding such as Latin-1, because it's their default for BOM-less text files.
In that case you see exactly the kind of distorted words like "acadÃ©mica".
Cf.:

```
>>>  'académica'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
'acadÃ©mica'
```

Now the question remains: why is the BOM missing?
After all, you are already using Python's "utf-8-sig" codec, which is UTF-8 with a BOM.
And you say that it works in write ("w") mode, but not in append ("a") mode.

By quickly testing with Python 3.5.2, I noticed that the BOM is not written in append mode, *unless the file didn't exist beforehand*.
This is sensible behaviour: the BOM isn't supposed to be repeated, you only want it once in the very beginning of the file, so when opening an existing file in append mode, you don't want it to start the new content with another BOM.

My guess is that you – unfamiliar with all those peculiar details – ended up somehow creating a file without BOM to start with, and then kept appending to it, which didn't retroactively introduce the BOM.
To be sure, you should start over by either removing/renaming "webscraped.csv", or by telling the scraper to write to a different target file which doesn't yet exist.